# Using filters on couchDB does not work

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase-lite

I am working in a project using `CouchDB` `CouchBase lite` and `Android`.
I want to use a [filter](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html) function so I am doing on my server end :

```
   {
   "_id": "_design/filters",
   "_rev": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "filters": {
       "master": "function(doc, req) { if(true==doc.ismaster) { return true; } else { return false; }}",
       "work": "function(doc, req) { if(true!=doc.ismaster) { return true; } else { return false; }}",
       "workdata": "function(doc, req){if (true==doc.ismaster){return false;}if (req.query.device_num==doc.device_num){return true;}if (doc.type=='field_order'){return true;}if (req.query.device_num=='20' || req.query.device_num=='21' || req.query.device_num=='22' || req.query.device_num=='23'){return true;}return false;}"
   }
}
```

On `Android` I am doing :

```
 pullwork = work.createPullReplication(url);
        pullwork.setAuthenticator(auth);
        if (PreferenceManager.getTabletNumber() > 80 && PreferenceManager.getTabletNumber() < 90) {
            pullwork.setFilter("filters/work");  
        }else {
            pullwork.setFilter("filters/workdata");
```

But It does not work as I expect and I am always getting just the master replication but never the work replication or the workdata replication.

Any idea about why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter functions aren't currently supported.  See [this section](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html#filtered-pull-from-couchdb-pouchdb-or-cloudant) in the Couchbase Lite docs.  (This was updated only a few weeks ago, so apologies if you saw an older version.)

You may also want to look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/issues/1776).  You can find more details on why it isn't supported.  Essentially, right now, the CouchDB docs don't describe what's needed well enough to implement compatibility.